# find image with specific src using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have some text with images within it. I want to replace specific images within the text with something else.

i.e. the text contains an a youtube img url that I want to replace with the actual video link.

```
<img class="mceItem" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/1MsVzAkmds0/default.jpg" alt="1MsVzAkmds0">
```

and replace it with the youtube Iframe code:

```
<iframe title="'.$id.'" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="576" height="400" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$id.'" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

my function looks like this:

```
function replacelink($link) {
  $find= ("/<img src=[^>]+\>/i");
  $replace = youtube("\\2");
  return preg_replace($find,$replace);
}
```

What do I need to change in the regex to do the above?

Comment: What is the "youtube" function?

Comment: ...if I could get the alt tag or src of the image I could send it to the youtube function youtube($id){ return iframe code ?$id=1MsVzAkmds0 } and display the iframe instead of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is looking for `<img src=`, but there is a `class` attribute between `img` and `src`. Using `$find= '/<img.*src=[^>]+>/i';` corrects the problem; however, this illustrates why you shouldn’t use regex to parse HTML.

You wrote:

> I have some text with images within it.

If the *text* you’re referring to is actually HTML, then there are better alternatives to using regex for this.

### Update

I believe this is what you’re looking for.

```php
<?php
function replacelink($text) {
    $replace = '<iframe title="$2" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="576" height="400" <iframe title="$2" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="576" height="400" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$2" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
    $find = '/(<img.*?alt="([\da-z]+)".*?>)/i';
    return preg_replace($find, $replace, $text);
}

$imagestr = '<img class="mceItem" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/1MsVzAkmds0/default.jpg" alt="1MsVzAkmds0">';
echo replacelink($imagestr);
?>
```

There’s no need for a separate `youtube()` function.

If you want to replace more than one image, use `preg_replace_all()` instead of `preg_replace()`.

Comment: @Innate: I just saw your comment about the `youtube()` function and updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex would get all the images with a specific url. I not sure if this is what you wanted.

```
<img [^>]*?src="url"[^>]*?>
```

Previous anwser would fail if there were more than one image.